# AWS MFA for users without console access, disable or what? Activate MFA on your root account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

What's the best practice for that?

I have ~ 10 users in IAM, only 3 of which are actual, human :), users with access to aws console.

Others have only aws key + secret key, programmatic access with permissions to only certain resources (f.e. s3 buckets for backup & etc).

Those non human users are listed as MFA NOT ENABLED in IAM & I still have a notification "Activate MFA on your root account".

How do I get rid of it? :)

Thanks!

Comment: root account is the owner of the account, email id with you signed up with not a IAM user.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran omg, that was it! Thanks! :)